# Manipulating 3rd party component DOM in Angular.js and without jQuery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

It's a common rule that when using angular.js, you should forget about jQuery's existence.

This gives me a hard time when dealing with 3rd party controls. As an example, let's consider we are using a library without official angular support, which takes a

```
<div id="searchWidgetDiv" />
```

and by calling the libraries `new SearchWidget('searchWidgetDiv')` method, it does initialize the control inside the div and adds several HTML tags like divs, spans or input tags. For example the DOM might look like that:

```
<div id="searchWidgetDiv">
   <div class="wrapper">
      <span class="title"></span>
      <input type="text" /> <input type="submit">
   </div>
</div>
```

Now I would like to add a CSS class to one of these children tags, or add some additional HTML tags depending on some user input or whatsoever.

As far as I understood, the angular way of dealing with DOM manipulation is to create directives. But a directive cannot influence the creation of HTML elements which takes place inside the SearchWidget constructor. So naturally, I see no other way than "hacking" that class into the DOM afterwards - a typical jQuery situation.

What is the angular way of doing this?

Comment: I don't understand what you really mean... If you create a directive, let's say <searchwidget></searchwidget>, you fill it with whatever you want, and use some ng-click, ng-class, ng-whatever or ng-something on your "directive's children" to do your dynamic stuff...

Comment: Thank you,  the problem is that searchwidgets children elements (like div, input, span tags or whatsoever), are created by the 3rd party components javascript code, and not within my directive. I don't understand how I can access these children

Comment: Can't you add them from within angularjs controller for example instead ?